# how to get data from an event in another class in flash as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, sockets

I have a class called socket.as and is responsible for socket connection etc. It has an event listener onSocketData, which is called whenever data is received. In my main class, Main.as, i have instantiated an object of socket class.

How can I get ***data*** from socket class?  Do i have to create a custom event in Main.as that should be triggered by socket class? 
Thank you.

below is the event listener from socket class:

```
private function onSocketData(event:ProgressEvent):void <br>
{
   //string sent over serial port.   
   var data:String = _socket.readUTFBytes( _socket.bytesAvailable );  

   var direction:int = 0;  

   buffer += data;  

 while((index = buffer.indexOf(EOL_DELIMITER)) > -1)
 {
  msg = buffer.substring(0, index-1);
  len = (buffer.indexOf(EOL_DELIMITER)) - 1;

  //remove the message from the buffer
  buffer = buffer.substring(index + 1);

  if ( msg != "off" )
  {
   button = parseInt(msg.substr(6, (len-8)));

   trace("Socket Data: " + msg + ", Button: " + button);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention , you could create a CustomEvent that will be triggered by the Socket class or you could dispatch an Event from the Socket class , whenever data is available and use a getter to retrieve the variable.

I've answered a similar question here:
[AS3 Passing data between objects/classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542538/as3-passing-data-between-objects-classes/4543414#4543414)

Comment: in case someone is interested here is what i did (Kinda what PatrickS mentioned):   right after button = parseInt(msg.substr(6, (len-8))); i did   dispatchEvent(new Event("onSocketData")); And then in main i added an listener for it _socket.addEventListener("onSocketData", _socketData); Since i had a getter function i used that to get my data inside the listener.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want to get data out, you can store it in an array in your class, and then have a method that pulls it out.

If, instead, you want to push up an event to Main.as, then you will need to create a custom event.

The easiest way to do this is to derive your class from `EventDispatcher`.

Then, when you want to fire an event, you just call `super.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(payload))` where `CustomEvent` is a class of yours that derives from `Event`.

The general pattern would look like this:

Create a custom event... unless an existing event class makes sense... then just reuse something else.

```
public class SocketEvent extends Event {
    public var payload:String;
    public function SocketEvent(payload:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false) {
        super(Socket.EVENT_NAME, bubbles, cancelable);
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

Then, the class that fires the event looks like this:

```
public class Socket extends EventDispatcher {
    public static const EVENT_NAME:String = "EVENT_NAME";

    private function fireTheEvent(payload:String):void {
        dispatchEvent(new SocketEvent(payload));
    }
}
```

Finally, to use it in Main.as, you would do this:

```
private var socket:Socket = new Socket();
socket.addEventListener(Socket.EVENT_NAME, actionHandler);
```

Note that this is NOT the only way to fire an event.  Another way would be to implement `IEventDispatcher` in terms of the static EventDispatcher methods... but that is a different example.

Comment: if i am using a getter function then i do not need to create a custom event class right?

Comment: plus don't we have to override the clone method if we are inheriting from Event class? Thank you

Comment: Right.  If you use a getter function, then there is no need for the event firing...  or, you can fire an `Event` with the name of "DataChanged" that tells the subscriber to call the getter.